# A keyboard for developers?

Tags: layout, buttons, keyboard

Being a software developer, the keyboard is the most important tool to interact with the computer. Thus, the layout and placement of buttons is very essential. Especially the grouping of the escape-button [ESC] and functional buttons [F1] - [F12]. On a [Standard Windows Natural Keyboard Layout](http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/keyboard/) the buttons are placed the way I've learned:

[image: Windows natural keyboard layout]

The palacement of the buttons on my old Windows Media Keyboard where the same, so I bought me a new one, not paying enough attention to the layout. Yes, It's my fault, because I didn't realize how important the layout is. Happy about my new Windows Media keyboard, I plugged it in and started working. The user experiance was horrible. Every time I hit the [ESC] button a new instance of Microsoft Outlook emerged on the screen. And trying to find the functional buttons just wasn't possible. They were missing. I couldn't find them because they were half the size of a normal button and being at a lower level than standard buttons. So I needed to look down on the keyboard every time to find them.

[image: Microsoft media keyboard 3000]

Two weeks later, I gave up. Now, I use the companion keyboard which was delivered with the computer. It works, but it is not what I want. I really need a new keyboard, with standard windows natural keyboard layout and silent buttons. *Microsoft* have the curved keyboard. *Logitech* also uses the half-size functional buttons and *Razor* have additional buttons above the row of functional buttons.

**Where do I find a keyboard for developers?**

Comment: This question, as asked, is off topic. Maybe you can try again, but instead of asking for a specific recommendation, put a UX spin on it. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I've edited the question to be another than a "let's go shopping-question". The answers up until todays timestamp (including my own) does not really answer the current edited question. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits on this one. The edits - while making the question more on-topic - totally invalidated all the answers that have already been left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks it's really a matter of taste. My favorite keyboard is the [Cherry eVolution](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=Cherry%20eVolution&hl=en&prmd=ivns&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1044&bih=740&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=15382297480040327413&sa=X&ei=4TK5Tb78CajO4wbb96kD&ved=0CE8Q8wIwAA#). It's a laptop style keyboard, very slim and silent keys.

An other option would be the [Das Keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/). Geeky and very nice. But not silent.

A programmer friend of mine absolutely loves his [Logitech Wave](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=logitech%20wave&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1044&bih=740&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=11460902568240930055&sa=X&ei=qDO5TYvzOpGS4gaTh9XNBQ&ved=0CHIQ8wIwAw#).

And of course there's the ultimate hacker keyboard, the [IBM Model M](http://www.google.com/search?q=IBM%20model%20m&hl=en&tbs=shop:1&aq=f).

Hope that helps, Phil

Comment: IBM Model M looks like the one for me - thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Colemak has been said to be a great alternative: http://colemak.com/

There is also a discussion about some alternative layouts on Coding Horror: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/we-are-typists-first-programmers-second.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

These things have a good 'feel' reputation - though I can't personally vouch for them.

If the 'super-cool-no symbols-look of the Ultimate Model' doesn't work for you try the Professional or Silent Models.

http://www.daskeyboard.com/